# Is It Possible To Shink Margins In Google Docs When Viewed in Mobile Browser

Tags: google-docs, iphone

I've created some Google Docs that look great on the desktop, but when viewed with iPhone Safari (in portrait orientation), the margins are so wide it squeezes the content inward too much. Is it possible to get the Gdoc to minimize the margins when viewed in a mobile browser?

additionally, images don't scale when viewed in the mobile browser. in documents that have a banner image at the top, when viewed on iPhone, it's width goes off-screen while the text is pushed in by the margins. its weird.

i know i can "request desktop version", but then that's not optimized for mobile viewing & requires horizontal scrolling to read the text.

these need to be dummy-proof when shared with multiple people on various devices & with varying degrees of technical know-how.

am i missing something or is this just not a capability of Google Docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are missing that according to [System requirements and browsers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2375082?hl=en) Safari is supported only on Mac. Instead using Safari on your iPhone, considere to use the Google Docs iOS app.

Comment: i need to send these documents to a variety of people. it's not realistic to tell them they can only view them on a desktop/laptop computer or to download another app. surely there's a way to get images & margins to scale on any  mobile device using any mobile browser. no?

Comment: Do you mean as a built-in feature of Google Docs? Unfortunately, AFAIK, there isn't. Maybe this is a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/289691) : instead of asking how to use Google Docs in an unsupported mobile web browser you might have to ask about what is the appropriate / more convenient way under certain criteria to share content (i.e. publishing the document to the web, export to and share PDF, among other options), or maybe you should ask for a software recommendation (the last is off-topic here, try [softwarerecs.se]).

Comment: ok. understood. THE ANSWER to my particular need is for anyone viewing on a phone NEEDS to go ahead & download the Google Docs App (unfortunately). all the formatting issues are resolved when viewed within the app. thx.